# Answer edited to add how to solve the question using a program

Tags: discussion, edits

In the question [MySQL error 1449: The user specified as a definer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169960/mysql-error-1449-the-user-specified-as-a-definer-does-not-exist) the last edit done on my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19707173/revisions) is adding how to accomplish the solution but using a specific program, MySQL Workbench. In my opinion, although it's adding value on how to do achieve it, it's out of the scope showing how to do it with a program, as this can lead to everybody editing the answer to add "how to do it with X".

What do you think? Should I rollback my answer? Should I add another paragraph for the proposed solution? Should I leave it as is?

Comment: I think the edit can be rolled back, unless you fancy to add other client-side tool options as well, like commandline or IDE's or phpMyAdmin

Comment: Yes, thanks @rene for pointing that out, I've corrected the question

Comment: The edit was not proper.  It looks completely unrelated so should have a separate answer.  However, I disagree that you think that answering a question with a tool/program is out of the scope.  Answering  a question with a solution that involves a tool or library is completely valid.